# Load variables from numpy arrays. Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

After the graph is created I would like to change the values of some variables according to given Numpy arrays. I don't want to send the values of the variables in the `feed_dict` because the values won't be changing very often. I also don't want to add another operation of the graph. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`tf.Variable.load()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable/#load). It doesn't add ops to the graph:

> Load new value into this variable.
>
> Writes new value to variable's memory. Doesn't add ops to the graph.

If you your are not in eager execution (via `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
import numpy as np

var = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2, 2])) # <-- existing variable

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(var.initializer)
    print('Current value:')
    print(var.eval())
    var.load(np.random.normal(size=(2, 2))) # <-- load new value
    print('New value:')
    print(var.eval())
# Current value:
# [[1. 1.]
#  [1. 1.]]
# New value:
# [[ 0.03251546  1.2442433 ]
#  [-1.4733697  -0.07199704]]
```

Notes on warning:

> Variable.load (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Prefer Variable.assign which has equivalent behavior in 2.X.

If you in graph mode the variable behaves exactly as in `TF1.x`. So using assign does add new ops to graph. For example, running following code in `jupyter`:

```py
%load_ext tensorboard.notebook
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops import placeholder
from tensorflow.python.summary.writer.writer import FileWriter

with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    x = placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name='x')
with tf.name_scope('logits'):
    layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2)
    logits = layer(x)
with tf.name_scope('assign'):
    assign_op = layer.weights[0].assign(np.random.normal(size=(2, 2)))
FileWriter('logs/train', graph=x.graph).close()
%tensorboard --logdir logs/train
```

[image]

As you can see it behaves exactly as in `TF1.x` (creates operations for assigning values for variables). The warning is for the cases where you write the code in `TF2.0` fashion (without `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`).

Comment: I used to use that on Tensorflow < 2.0. But the new version gives the following warning:

```Variable.load (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Prefer Variable.assign which has equivalent behavior in 2.X.```

Comment: You talked about graph, I assumed that you have used graph mode in `TF2.0`. I'll update my question

Comment: I am talking about the graph mode

Comment: Did you do `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`, or do you want to update the variable within `@tf.function`?

Comment: I have updated my answer. The warning is irrelevant if you use graph mode. Don't forget it is `alpha` version and still has a lot of `bugs`/inaccuracies in docs etc.